# Nginx permanant redirection url

Tags: regex, url, redirect, nginx

Need to make a little bit complex permanent redirection with nginx.

There are two example of what I'm trying to do

Example 1:
https://www.website.com/attractions-in-$city-$cityID-$country => https://www.website.com/things-to-do-in-$city-$country

Example 2:
www.website.com/attractions-reviews-$name-in-$city-$cityID-$country => www.website.com/things-to-do-reviews-$name-in-$city-$country

Please not that for the $city and $country variables I need to get the correct slug pattern, example: south africa => south_africa.

Comment: Hi ! It would be better if you checkout [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code for future endeavor at Stack overflow. -Thank you

Comment: How are the slug patterns changing - from what to what? The solution will probably involve a `rewrite` statement with captures - which part are you stuck on?

Comment: May we see what you've tried? What area of the NginX documentation are you looking at currently?